# How to get share count of a linkedin post using linkedin API?

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I am able to get the count and other details of likes and comments for the posts that i posted over my Linkedin page through some API.But i couldn't get the count of  how many times the posts are shared from my page. I saw  similar questions in stackoverflow ,But i didn't find any solution. please  give a solution. thanks in advance..